# Firebase database how to get some value from 1 reference and equals to 2 reference to get its keys and values

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have users info as show below

[image: user]

I want to to check if `commentWriterUid` is equals to one from users key to get its info

[image: comment]

I tried this:

```
Query query = mDatabaseReference_comments.orderByChild("commentWriterUid").equalTo(FirebaseUtil.getUsersReference().getKey());

        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                userModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserModel.class);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        mFirebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<CommentModel, CommentViewHolder>(CommentModel.class,
                R.layout.layout_comment,
                CommentViewHolder.class,
                mDatabaseReference_comments) {

            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(CommentViewHolder viewHolder, CommentModel model, int position) {

                Glide.with(PostCommentActivity.this)
                        .load(userModel.getUserImageUrl())
                        .into(viewHolder.mCircleImageView_commentWriterImage);

                viewHolder.mTextView_commentWriterName.setText(userModel.getUserName());

                viewHolder.bindToPost(PostCommentActivity.this, model);

            }

        };
```

But I get these errors:

```
03-04 02:24:34.558 31063-31063/com.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.app.PostCommentActivity$4.populateViewHolder(PostCommentActivity.java:119)
    at com.app.PostCommentActivity$4.populateViewHolder(PostCommentActivity.java:113)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one answer my question so i figured it my own and answer this so it may be helpful for others

```html
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        final DatabaseReference root_ref = firebaseDatabase.getReference();

        root_ref.child("comments").child("KeKwGa5btKuDYr3yYq5").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String commentWriterUid = dataSnapshot.child("commentWriterUid").getValue().toString();

                root_ref.child("users").equalTo(commentWriterUid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        // Do all stuff you went

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```